# Zend Dojo Element Id missing

Tags: css, zend-framework, dojo

I am creating a Zend Form using Dojo elements and I would like to layout the form elements using CSS. Unfortunatly the  element is not being given an ID like all other elements in my form.

Output

```
<dt id="purchase_required-label"></dt>
<dd><table id="widget_purchase_required" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable disabled dijitTextBox dijitTextBoxDisabled" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" wairole="presentation" dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse" name="purchase_required" style="display: -moz-inline-stack;" role="presentation" widgetid="purchase_required"></table></dd>
<dt id="purchase_supplier_id-label"></dt>
<dd id="purchase_supplier_id-element"></dd>
```

Example Code

```
$purchase_required = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_DateTextBox('purchase_required');
$purchase_required->setLabel('Required Date');
$purchase_required->setAttribs(array("dojoType"=>"dijit.form.DateTextBox"));
$purchase_required->setRequired(TRUE);
$purchase_required->addErrorMessage('Please enter date as YYYY-MM-DD');
$this->addElement($purchase_required);
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that id is removed from that element in `Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_Dijit` when it overrides [`loadDefaultDecorators`](http://phpcrossref.com/zendframework/library/Zend/Dojo/Form/Element/Dijit.php.html#l151). You could probably restore it by using something like what happens in Dijit's superclass: [`Zend_Form_Element`](http://phpcrossref.com/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Element.php.html#l305):

```
$getId = create_function('$decorator',
                             'return $decorator->getElement()->getId()
                                     . "-element";');
$purchase_required->addDecorator(
         'HtmlTag', 
         array(
               'tag' => 'dd',
               'id'  => array('callback' => $getId)
              )
);
```